# Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0 after downloading code from git onto new machine

Tags: cors, system.web.http

I have been given an updated laptop at work and have checked in everything then pulled down to my new machine.. having then spent virtually the whole day sorting out all the Nuget references and reinstalling packages etc... I am now getting the error in the subject line...

Note that it is looking for System.Web.Cors and not System.Web.Http.Cors.dll which does exist...

below is my packages.config..

```
 <packages>
    <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Autofac" version="4.0.0-rc1-177" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="4.0.0-beta7-215" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="6.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.6.2" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" version="1.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" version="1.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.0.1-beta-23516" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension" version="5.2.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="7.0.1-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  </packages>
```

and my web config relevant section is...

```
</dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>


      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>
```

The project builds okay, with a few warnings, but on running it locally in debug i get the error

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 42:             config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
Line 43:             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
Line 44:             GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
Line 45:             FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
Line 46:             RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```